# convert 2010-04-15 23:59:59 to 15th Apr 2010

Tags: javascript, datetime, nlp

I have the following date format: `2010-04-15 23:59:59`

How would I go about converting this into: `15th Apr 2010`

using javascript

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/). You'll probably want to parse your timestamp and then call `toString('MMS MMM yyyy')` (or something to that effect) on it. Here's some more info on [toString](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers).

There's probably a more-lightweight solution, if this is all you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Like dylanfm suggests, I would check out [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/), but if you only want to convert the way you are describing, this might work for you:

```
 var m = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
 var p = ["th","st","nd","rd"];

 // create date object - have to replace dashes with slashes
 var d = new Date("2010-04-15 23:59:59".replace(/-/g,"/"));

 // index in array p based on date % 10
 var pn = d.getDate() % 10;

 // pick "th" for days 11-13
 if (d.getDate() > 10 && d.getDate() < 14 ) pn = 0;

 // pick "th" for days 4-9, 14-19, 24-29
 if (pn >= p.length) pn = 0;

 // date in format "15th Apr 2010"
 var formatted = d.getDate() + p[pn] + " " + m[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();
```

Note that this is nowhere near as flexible as using a library like Datejs.